# Strange behavior using goto for error handling in C

Tags: c, goto, trustzone

I am developing a basic application in C, using the OP-TEE (TrustZone Secure OS) libraries. I am running the code in QEMU. Here is the code in which the strange behavior occurred:

```
void prepare_rsa_operation(TEE_OperationHandle *handle, uint32_t alg, TEE_OperationMode mode, TEE_ObjectHandle key) {
    TEE_Result ret = TEE_SUCCESS;   
    TEE_ObjectInfo key_info;

    ret = TEE_GetObjectInfo1(key, &key_info);
    if (ret != TEE_SUCCESS) {
        EMSG("TEE_GetObjectInfo1: %#" PRIx32, ret);
        goto err;
    }

    ret = TEE_AllocateOperation(handle, alg, mode, key_info.keySize);
    if (ret != TEE_SUCCESS) {
        EMSG("Failed to alloc operation handle : 0x%x", ret);
        goto err;
    }
    DMSG("========== Operation allocated successfully. ==========");

    ret = TEE_SetOperationKey(*handle, key);
    if (ret != TEE_SUCCESS) {
        EMSG("Failed to set key : 0x%x", ret);
        goto err;
    }
    DMSG("========== Operation key already set. ==========");

err:
    TEE_FreeOperation(handle);
    return 1;
}
```

Problem that occurred:
Both successful messages were being printed (for operation allocated and key setting), but the `err` label was being reached even though: the `TEE_FreeOperation(handle);` should be written `TEE_FreeOperation(*handle);`. I fixed this and removed the `return`, since my function returns `void`. Now, the code is working fine, but, in my understanding, the `err` label should be reached only if one of the conditional tests (`if`'s) fail, since the `goto` command is just inside them.

Am I wrong with this understanding? Can anyone explain me why the `err` label was being reached even though no error occurred before?

Comment: Add a `return;` just before the `err:` BTW your function is defined to return void, you still attempt to `return 1;`

Comment: You reach the `err` label regardless because the normal execution of your code gets to it.  Labels don't stop code that reaches them naturally.

Comment: Yes, @joop . As I said in the question, I removed the `return`; but, still, I thought this should be identified in compilation time, not just in runtime (in my humble opinion).

Comment: Good, @Christian . So, this is the normal flow, since I did not stop the program before the label in any part, right?

Comment: @DaltonCézane my gcc warns me, even without the `-Wall` or `-pedantic` flags.

Comment: Thank you by your comments, @joop and Christian .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no special logic that prevents code from progressing past a label.

By convention, `goto` is typically used in C for this type of error handing but it doesn't have to be that way.  Labels for `goto` can be freely placed anywhere in a function.  You could for example do this:

```
void f()
{
    int i;
start:
    printf("i=%d\n", i);
    i++;
    if (i < 10) {
        goto start;
}
```

But please don't.

Answer (score 3):

The `err:` label is reached either if you `goto` it or after executing `DMSG("========== Operation key already set. ==========");`. Meaning you get a clean-up no matter if the function was successful or not. That's the whole reason for using "on error goto" patterns to begin with.

A more readable alternative to the goto, is to return upon error and leave the clean-up in an external wrapper function.

Answer (score 1):

A labeled statement doesn't get skipped over if it's reached through normal flow of execution.  IOW, given code like

```
if ( condition )
{
  goto err;
}

err:
  // error handling code

// regular code
```

If `condition` evaluates to false, the code following `err` still gets executed because it follows the `if` statement.  You can avoid it by using second label and `goto`:

```
if ( condition )
{
  goto err;
}
goto normal;

err:
  // error handling code

normal:
  // regular code
```

but figuring out a goto-less way to handle the problem is better.

Comment: "but figuring out a goto-less way to handle the problem is better."  Not necessarily:  https://koblents.com/Ches/Links/Month-Mar-2013/20-Using-Goto-in-Linux-Kernel-Code/

Answer (score 1):

Much like Case labels in a switch-case statement, a label will just fall through to the next instruction when reached through the normal flow of code.  It is simply a place that can be jumped to.  This functionality is taken advantage of when doing clean-up after an error.  For example, if you're mallocing a bunch of things and an error occurs, you can jump to different sections of the clean up code depending on when you hit your error:

```
int func(void) {
    int ret = -1;
    int *x = malloc(sizeof(*x));
    if (/* some error condition */) {
        goto CLEANUP1;
    }
    int *y = malloc(sizeof(*y));
    if (/* some error condition */) {
        goto CLEANUP2;
    }
    int *z = malloc(sizeof(*z));
    if (/* some error condition */) {
        goto CLEANUP3;
    }
    ret = 0;
    /* do whatever successful operations you want here */

    CLEANUP3:
    free(z);
    CLEANUP2:
    free(y);
    CLEANUP1:
    free(x);
    return ret;
}
```

So with the above snippet, with normal error-free execution, all of the `malloc`'d variables get `free`d before leaving the function.  If there is an error after `malloc`ing `x`, you jump to the `CLEANUP1` label and `free` `x`.  if there is an error after `malloc`ing `z`, then you've also `malloc`'d `x` and `y`, so you jump to the `CLEANUP3` label which will `free` `z` and then fall through to the other two `free`s.